# How do I make JavaScript open page depending on device?

Tags: javascript

I recently made a website for a bit of fun. I had an idea to use JavaScript to open link depending on the device.(when JavaScript detects a device lets say a desktop it will open YouTube and when it detects a phone it will open google). Please don't judge as I know **NOTHING** about JavaScript but here is what I came up with:

```html
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i);

window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
```

This really doesn't work so if anyone knows how to crack this and open a website depending on the device I would be greatful as I am interested.

Comment: User Agent sniffing is a huge, huge, tangled, [incestuous](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) (thanks IE) mess.  MDN has a good article on some of things to keep in mind: [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent).  Only do it if you want an exercise in insanity.

Comment: You don't end `if` statements with a `;`.  You need to use `{}` after your `if`.  Like `if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i)) { window.open(''); }`

Comment: Please also explain what you mean by "doesn't work".  First off, I see you wrote `if (...);` which isn't a very useful if statement.  Did you mean to use `{}` after the if?

Comment: I think you forget to close your if block with )

Comment: Ok here is an update for those confused:
 <h1 id="platform"></h1>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  var platform = document.getElementById('platform');

  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
   platform.textContent = "It's iPhone";
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
   platform.textContent = "It's iPad";
  } else if(screen.width <= 699) {
   platform.textContent = "It's Mobile";
  } else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i)) {
   platform.textContent = "It's Mac!!";
  } else {
   platform.a.href  = "www.google.com";
  }
Is this right?

Comment: @zero298 lol I am just trying something new but the dudes on here seem helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open YouTube when the user is on desktop or Google when they are on mobile, checking the screen size is much easier and more convenient. You haven't got JavaScript syntax right, but it's actually quite simple:

```js
if (window.outerWidth > 1000) {
  window.location.replace('https://youtube.com')
} else {
  window.location.replace('https://google.com')
}
```

Comment: And if I shrink my browser window?  What about a landscape iPad?  Pretty sure those are longer than 1000px.

Comment: @zero298 checking the user agent can also be fooled simply by opening device preview in DevTools. We can safely assume that most users won't do that

Comment: @zero298 the pixel values can be adjusted for tablet, mobile, desktop and laptop. iPads actually fool user agent detectors, since by default Safari loads desktop view of all sites

Comment: You're proving my point, this check won't even come close to being able to get it right every time.  There is no fool-proof way of doing this.

Comment: @zero298 I do agree with you, but since this is not a production site, that shouldn't be a problem. The OP mentioned that it was just for fun